# Image uploading and storing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-ec2, paperclip

I am using 'paperclip' gem to upload images/files in development. It usually stores files in tmp folder. All good in development but not in production.

I have two questions here.

1) In heroku, I was able to upload images. But, they get deleted after some time. 
Why is this happening? The files are obviously stored at some location when we upload files into heroku. Why are they getting deleted?

2) In AWS ec2, I couldn't upload images/files. Do I need to set permissions to store files into public folder? Installed rmagick too to make paperclip work. I don't know what details to post.

Noob here!

**Edit:**
Second question is a repetition: I'm linking the post here. [paperclip working in development but not working in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101214/paperclip-working-in-development-but-not-working-in-production)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Your Heroku images are being deleted by your new commits (every time you commit to Heroku, it replaces all your files with new ones - including your `images` dir). The [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) gives you a description of why this happens

2) From my understanding, `AWS/EC2` is only for processing - you'll need to [store your assets (inc `images`) in an `S3` bucket](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3). Paperclip natively works with S3, meaning you'll be able to store your images in S3 regardless of whether you're running on `AWS` or `Heroku`

---

**Paperclip**

Since you're a beginner, here are some details for Paperclip:

```
#app/models/image.rb
Class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end

#config/application.rb
:storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

You need to be aware that Paperclip doesn't actually "store" the images - it simply transfers them to different locations & creates db entries. This means the only thing you should worry about for Paperclip will be where it gets stored, and what sizes the images are (with `rMagick`)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku keeps uploaded images only for few time and then delete it automatically because heroku has only read only file system.
Read following for more details >>https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

If you want to use amazon web services then check out this documentation ,this would be very helpful for you.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3