# file_field does not choose files in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, file-upload, paperclip

I am using Paperclip to manage files.

File upload works perfectly in development, but in production environment file_field tag is not choosing anything.

Form:

```
<div class="change-avatar">
   <%= form_for @user, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <%= f.file_field :avatar, id: "avatarInput" %>
      <a id="avatarInput_alt">Change avatar</a>
      <%= f.submit id: "submitAvatar"%>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

The dialog is being showed when I click on the 'Choose file' button, but after I choose a file it still shows `no file selected`.

When I call `document.getElementById("avatarInput").files` the output is `FileList {length: 0, item: function}`.

Does anyone know what is wrong?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101214/paperclip-working-in-development-but-not-working-in-production

Comment: @HieuPham I believe the problem occurs before the app gets to the backend. The issue seems to be on the client.